# What are the typical use-cases for "attributes" and "classes" in R?

Tags: r, class, attributes

From [Advanced R section 3.3](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#attributes):

> You might have noticed that the set of atomic vectors does not include
> a number of important data structures like matrices, arrays, factors,
> or date-times. These types are built on top of atomic vectors by
> adding attributes.

From [Advanced R section 3.4](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#s3-atomic-vectors):

> One of the most important vector attributes is class, which underlies
> the S3 object system. Having a class attribute turns an object into an
> S3 object, which means it will behave differently from a regular
> vector when passed to a generic function. Every S3 object is built on
> top of a base type, and often stores additional information in other
> attributes.

Thus, I would say, "class" is more than "attribute". On the other hand, it seems `data.frame` can serve as an `attribute` but not really as `class`. What are the typical use cases then?
(I could look at existing code, of course. But this feels more like bad reverse engineering than "know what you do")

**Example**: Should I use

```
mydata <- c(1:10)
attr(mydata, "x") <- "x-attribute"
attributes(mydata)
# $x
# [1] "x-attribute"
```

or

```
mydata <- c(1:10)
class(mydata) <- "x"
class(mydata)
# [1] "x"
attributes(mydata)
# $class
# [1] "x"
```

In the latter case,

```
print.x <- function(x) print.default(paste0("This is ", paste(x, collapse = " / ")))
plot.x <- function(x) plot.default(rep(1, length(x)), x, xlab = "great", main = "x")
print(mydata)
# [1] "This is 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 / 6 / 7 / 8 / 9 / 10"
plot(mydata)
```

works as expected. But which is "better"?

A `data.frame` attribute seems not useful:

```
mydata <- c(1:10)
attr(mydata, "x") <- "x-attribute"
attr(mydata, "y") <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2), y=c(3, 4))
attributes(mydata)
# $x
# [1] "x-attribute"
# 
# $y
# x y
# 1 1 3
# 2 2 4
```

(Can't make `print.???` or `plot.`??? work...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "class" attribute is what determines generic method dispatch. A data frame has the "class" attribute set to the *string* "data.frame", which is what allows generic functions like `format`, `print` and even mathematical operators to treat it differently from, say, a numeric vector.

Attributes other than class are used in different ways, often to store information that the class needs to work properly but can be hidden from the user when not required.

For example, a grouped `tibble` has a vector of `row.names` stored as an attribute, the column names stored as a character vector inside an attribute, and the groups stored inside a tibble as an attribute called `groups`. The latter is a good example of a data frame that is stored as an attribute and does useful work.

```r
as_tibble(iris) %>% group_by(Species) %>% attr('groups')
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Species          .rows
#>   <fct>      <list<int>>
#> 1 setosa            [50]
#> 2 versicolor        [50]
#> 3 virginica         [50]
```

This attribute is normally hidden from end-users, because it is not printed by the tibble's `print` method, but it is vital for a grouped tibble to work as it should.

It is easy to set up an example to show how class and other attributes can be used in a single object. Suppose we wanted to be able to time stamp an object on its creation so that it keeps a record of its creation date, but we don't want that to be visible to the user unless they specifically ask for it.

First, we have a class creator (this may be the optimal way to create a class, incidentally, rather than simply setting a class attribute)

```r
timestamp <- function(x) {
  structure(x, created_on = Sys.Date(), class = c('timestamp', class(x)))
}
```

Now we create a print method that doesn't display the timestamp.

```r
print.timestamp <- function(x) {
  attr(x, 'created_on') <- NULL
  class(x) <- class(x)[-1]
  NextMethod()
}
```

Finally, we can create a little generic function to check timestamps on created objects. If the object is not timestamped, this should return an error:

```r
creation_date <- function(x) UseMethod('creation_date')

creation_date.default <- function(x) stop('No timestamp on this object')

creation_date.timestamp <- function(x) {
  attr(x, 'created_on')
}
```

So testing now, we can create a timestamped object, which looks exactly like a non-timestamped object:

```r
object <- timestamp(1:10)

object
#> [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

But under the radar it contains other useful information that the object might need to function as expected:

```r
creation_date(object)
#> [1] "2022-09-30"
```

Comment: Great examples, I realized, that some data which I used to provide via part of a list should be an attribute! (I used time stamps:-))

Comment: @Christoph the S3 system is pretty lax, and often wrapping everything as a list instead of using attributes is a perfectly reasonable solution. Attributes have a tendency to disappear easily when carrying out common operations like subsetting or concatenation. Sometimes that's desirable, other times a list may be better.